# vlcj application optimization

Tags: java, video, video-processing, vlcj

Hi friends I'm actually developing my own video player, using VLCJ libraries , I use a canvas over a JFrame and a options bar with buttons to play,stop etc..
in this moment the video player and all the buttons works, but
it is so slow and the fps are so low too, I think that using a canvas is not the best method to play videos , or maybe my code is not optimized .

Main class:

```
package vlcvideo;

import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class VlcVideo {
    static JFileChooser filex = new JFileChooser();

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
      String rutaVlc = "C:/vlc64/vlc";
      String rutaVideo="/src/vlcVideo/c.mp4";
      File ourFile;

      //seleccionar la ruta de instalacion del vlc
     /*filex.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);//selecciona solo directorios
      filex.showSaveDialog(null);
      ourFile=filex.getSelectedFile();
      rutaVlc=ourFile.getAbsolutePath();*/
    /*  
      filex.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
      filex.showSaveDialog(null);
      ourFile=filex.getSelectedFile();
      rutaVideo=ourFile.getAbsolutePath();*/

        System.out.println(rutaVlc + "ruta DLL");
        System.out.println(rutaVideo + " ruta video");
        //new MediaPlayer(rutaVlc,rutaVideo).run();
       //MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(rutaVlc,rutaVideo);

       prueba pb = new prueba(rutaVlc,rutaVideo);
      //  reproductor rp = new reproductor(rutaVlc,rutaVideo);
         // rp.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Frame class:

```
    package vlcvideo;

import com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary;
/*import com.xuggle.xuggler.IContainer;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.ICodec;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IStream;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IStreamCoder;*/


import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;


import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.MediaPlayerFactory;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.EmbeddedMediaPlayer;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.runtime.RuntimeUtil;


public class prueba extends javax.swing.JFrame 
{
    private static final int SKIP_TIME_MS = 10 * 1000;
    private boolean mousePressedPlaying = false;
    Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Dimension tm = tk.getScreenSize();
    private final String vlc;
    Canvas c;
    private final String video;
    EmbeddedMediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    public prueba(String vlc,String video)     
    {  
        this.video=video;
        this.vlc=vlc;
        initComponents();
        initMyComponentes();
        createCanvas();
        createMedia();
        printTime();
    }
    public void printTime()
    {
      /*while(true)
        {
            final long time = mediaPlayer.getTime(); 
               final int position = (int)(mediaPlayer.getPosition() * 1000.0f);
               final int chapter = mediaPlayer.getChapter();
               final int chapterCount = mediaPlayer.getChapterCount();
               int posicionSlider=positionSlider.getValue();
            if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) 
            {
                 updateTime(time);
                 updatePosition(position);
                 updateChapter(chapter, chapterCount);
              }
        }  */
        timeThread tt = new timeThread(this,mediaPlayer);
        tt.start();
    }
    public void createCanvas()
    {
        c = new Canvas();
        c.setBackground(Color.black);
        int panelHeight  = panelVideo.getHeight();
        int panelWidth = panelVideo.getWidth();
        System.out.println(panelHeight + "  "  +panelWidth);
        c.setBounds(0, 0,panelWidth, panelHeight);
        panelVideo.add(c);
    }
    public void initMyComponentes()
    {
        positionSlider.setMinimum(0);
        positionSlider.setMaximum(1000);
        positionSlider.setValue(0);
        positionSlider.setToolTipText("Position");
        volumeSlider.setOrientation(JSlider.HORIZONTAL);
        volumeSlider.setToolTipText("Change volume");
        System.out.println(tm.height +  "  *   "+tm.width);
    }
   /* public void duracion()
    {
        IContainer container = IContainer.make();   
        int result = container.open(video, IContainer.Type.READ, null);
        if(result<0)
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to open media file");
        long duration = container.getDuration();
        System.out.println("Duration (ms): " + duration);
    }*/
    public void createMedia()
    {
        NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(),vlc);
        MediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory();
        mediaPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setVideoSurface(mediaPlayerFactory.newVideoSurface(c));
        mediaPlayer.toggleFullScreen();
        mediaPlayer.setEnableMouseInputHandling(false);
        mediaPlayer.setEnableKeyInputHandling(true);
        mediaPlayer.prepareMedia(video);
        mediaPlayer.play();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        panelVideo = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        btnMute = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnPlay = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnPause = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnStop = new javax.swing.JButton();
        positionSlider = new javax.swing.JSlider();
        lblTime = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        chapterLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        volumeSlider = new javax.swing.JSlider();
        btnRewind = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnRewind2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        lblTotal = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 51, 51));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout panelVideoLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(panelVideo);
        panelVideo.setLayout(panelVideoLayout);
        panelVideoLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            panelVideoLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        panelVideoLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            panelVideoLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 256, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        btnMute.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/fotos/mute.jpg"))); // NOI18N
        btnMute.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnMuteActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnPlay.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/fotos/Play.png"))); // NOI18N
        btnPlay.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnPlayActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnPause.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/fotos/Pause.jpg"))); // NOI18N
        btnPause.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnPauseActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnStop.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/fotos/stop.jpg"))); // NOI18N
        btnStop.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnStopActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        positionSlider.setMinorTickSpacing(10);
        positionSlider.setPaintTicks(true);
        positionSlider.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                positionSliderMousePressed(evt);
            }
            public void mouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                positionSliderMouseReleased(evt);
            }
        });

        lblTime.setText("0");

        chapterLabel.setText("00/00");

        volumeSlider.setMinorTickSpacing(10);
        volumeSlider.setPaintLabels(true);
        volumeSlider.setPaintTicks(true);
        volumeSlider.setToolTipText("");
        volumeSlider.addChangeListener(new javax.swing.event.ChangeListener() {
            public void stateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {
                volumeSliderStateChanged(evt);
            }
        });

        btnRewind.setText("<<");
        btnRewind.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnRewindActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnRewind2.setText(">>");
        btnRewind2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnRewind2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        lblTotal.setText("/0t");

        jLabel1.setText("Volumen");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(178, 178, 178)
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(panelVideo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(btnPlay, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 47, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(btnPause, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 43, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(btnStop, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 44, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(61, 61, 61)
                        .addComponent(positionSlider, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 250, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(91, 91, 91))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(171, 171, 171)
                        .addComponent(lblTime)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(lblTotal)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 152, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(btnRewind)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)))
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(chapterLabel)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addGap(37, 37, 37)
                        .addComponent(btnMute, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 26, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(19, 19, 19))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(1, 1, 1)
                        .addComponent(btnRewind2)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 109, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(volumeSlider, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 128, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(34, 34, 34))))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(panelVideo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(33, 33, 33)
                                .addComponent(positionSlider, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                    .addComponent(lblTime)
                                    .addComponent(lblTotal)))
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(chapterLabel)
                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                            .addComponent(btnRewind)
                                            .addComponent(btnRewind2)))
                                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                            .addComponent(jLabel1)
                                            .addComponent(btnMute, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 18, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                        .addComponent(volumeSlider, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))))
                        .addContainerGap())
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(btnPause, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 45, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(btnPlay)
                            .addComponent(btnStop, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 45, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(19, 19, 19))))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void btnPlayActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        mediaPlayer.play();
    }                                       

    private void btnPauseActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }                                        

    private void btnStopActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        mediaPlayer.stop();

    }                                       

    private void btnMuteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
         mediaPlayer.mute();

    }                                       

    private void positionSliderMousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                            
                if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mousePressedPlaying = true;
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                }
                else 
                {
                    mousePressedPlaying = false;
                }
                setSliderBasedPosition();
    }                                           

    private void positionSliderMouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                             
       setSliderBasedPosition();
                updateUIState();
    }                                            

    private void volumeSliderStateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {                                          
        JSlider source = (JSlider)evt.getSource();
                // if(!source.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                mediaPlayer.setVolume(source.getValue());
                // }
    }                                         

    private void btnRewindActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        skip(-SKIP_TIME_MS);
    }                                         

    private void btnRewind2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        skip(SKIP_TIME_MS);
    }                                          
    public void setSliderBasedPosition() 
    {
        if(!mediaPlayer.isSeekable()) {
            return;
        }
        float positionValue = positionSlider.getValue() / 1000.0f;
        // Avoid end of file freeze-up
        if(positionValue > 0.99f) {
            positionValue = 0.99f;
        }
        mediaPlayer.setPosition(positionValue);
    }    
    private void updateUIState() 
    {
            if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                // Resume play or play a few frames then pause to show current position in video
                mediaPlayer.play();
                if(!mousePressedPlaying) {
                    try {
                        // Half a second probably gets an iframe
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    }
                    catch(InterruptedException e) {
                        // Don't care if unblocked early
                    }
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                }
            }
            long time = mediaPlayer.getTime();
            int position = (int)(mediaPlayer.getPosition() * 1000.0f);
            int chapter = mediaPlayer.getChapter();
            int chapterCount = mediaPlayer.getChapterCount();
            updateTime(time);
            updatePosition(position);
            updateChapter(chapter, chapterCount);
        }
    public void skip(int skipTime) 
    {
        // Only skip time if can handle time setting
        if(mediaPlayer.getLength() > 0) {
            mediaPlayer.skip(skipTime);
            updateUIState();
        }
    }
    public void updateTime(long millis) 
    {
        String s = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
        lblTime.setText(s);
    }
    public void updatePosition(int value) 
    {
        // positionProgressBar.setValue(value);
        positionSlider.setValue(value);
    }
    public void updateChapter(int chapter, int chapterCount) {
        String s = chapterCount != -1 ? (chapter + 1) + "/" + chapterCount : "-";
        chapterLabel.setText(s);
        chapterLabel.invalidate();
        validate();
    }

    public void updateVolume(int value) {
        volumeSlider.setValue(value);
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton btnMute;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnPause;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnPlay;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnRewind;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnRewind2;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnStop;
    private javax.swing.JLabel chapterLabel;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblTime;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblTotal;
    private javax.swing.JPanel panelVideo;
    public javax.swing.JSlider positionSlider;
    private javax.swing.JSlider volumeSlider;
    // End of variables declaration                   

}
```

The Thread used for print the time:

```
package vlcvideo;

import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.EmbeddedMediaPlayer;

public class timeThread extends Thread
{
    prueba pb;
    EmbeddedMediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    public timeThread(prueba pb,EmbeddedMediaPlayer mediaPlayer)
    {
        this.pb=pb;
        this.mediaPlayer=mediaPlayer;
    }
    public void run()
   {
       while(true)
        {
            final long time = mediaPlayer.getTime(); 
               final int position = (int)(mediaPlayer.getPosition() * 1000.0f);
               final int chapter = mediaPlayer.getChapter();
               final int chapterCount = mediaPlayer.getChapterCount();
               int posicionSlider=pb.positionSlider.getValue();
            if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) 
            {
                 pb.updateTime(time);
                 pb.updatePosition(position);
                 pb.updateChapter(chapter, chapterCount);
             }
        }      
   }
}
```

libraries used:

```
-jna 3.4.0.jar
-vlcj 2.1.0.jar
```

jdk:1.8

Answer (score 1):

You have a tight loop in your thread that will consume just about all of your CPU.

Rather than polling inside a tight loop you should use media player events to get the information you want.

Or at worst you should sleep in that loop.